# Value of an array is changing without assignment

Tags: java

I am using just this code to flip a row in a 2 dimensional matrix in java. it seems like such a simple code but for some reason, it is not working. The rowN of a matrix was originally

```
112 42 83 119
```

became

```
119 83 83 119
```

I debugged the code and found out that the tempMatrix2 is also being changed. I can't understand why. It changes in the for loop in the same line in which I am assigning value to matrix[rowN][i].
Any help is appreciated.

```
static int[][] flipRow(int[][] matrix, int rowN, int n) {
    int[] tempMatrix2 = matrix[rowN];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        matrix[rowN][i] = tempMatrix2[n-i-1];
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: `matrix[rowN]` and `tempMatrix2` are the same array. Modifying one will modify the other.

Comment: When you do `int[] tempMatrix2 = matrix[rowN];` you're creating a second *reference* to the same array object on the heap. That's why. For your algorithm to work you need to make a *copy*. But there are much easier ways to flip - go halfway into the array only and *swap* values with the other half.

Comment: Even easier might be `List<Integer> reverser = Arrays.asList(matrix[rowN]); Collections.reverse(reverser); matrix[rowN] = reverser;`. Or switch to a more functional paradigm, like [streams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-stream) or [kotlin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin).

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I actually did that but just wanted to know why this particular code doesn't work. thnx anyway

Comment: Do you now understand why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

In this case tempMatrix2 and matrix are pointing to the same place in the heap memory.

If you change the array value in matrix, it will be reflected in the tempMatrix2 and vice versa.

```
Original array {112, 42, 83, 119}

Here, n = 4
For example, let's say rowN = 0

When i = 0,
matrix[0][0] = tempMatrix[0][3];
The state is now:
matrix = {119, 42, 83, 119},
tempMatrix = {119, 42, 83, 119 }

When i = 1,
matrix[0][1] = tempMatrix[0][2];
Since tempMatrix[0][2] = 83, 
matrix = {119, 83, 83, 119},
tempMatrix = {119, 83, 83, 119 }
```

Instead of doing tempMatrix2 = matrix, you need to create a new integer array object and assign that to tempMatrix2 and then copy all the values from the matrix array into this new object. Here is how I suggest doing it:

```
static int[][] flipRow(int[][] matrix, int rowN, int n) {
    int[] tempMatrix2 = new int[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        tempMatrix2[i] = matrix[rowN][i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        matrix[rowN][i] = tempMatrix2[n-i-1];
    }

    return matrix;
}
```